# c# Configuration --> query and obtain values for a multi-tenant appsettings.json

Tags: c#, configuration, console-application, .net-7.0

I'm working with a multi-tenant `appsettings.json` and I want to know how to get a list of features by the `tenantID` based on the below `appsettings.json` configuration

```
"Multitenancy": {
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "Name": "Tenant1",
        "TenantId": "21341234-2134-2134-2134-123412342134",
        //other settings in here
        "Features": {
          "FeatureName1": true,
          "FeatureName2": true,
          "FeatureName3": false,
          "FeatureName4": true,
          "FeatureName5": false,
          "FeatureName6": true,
        },
        //more settings
     },
     {
        "Name": "Tenant2",
        "TenantId": "12341234-2134-1234-1234-123412341234",
        //other settings in here
        "Features": {
          "FeatureName1": true,
          "FeatureName2": true,
          "FeatureName3": false,
          "FeatureName4": true,
          "FeatureName5": false,
          "FeatureName6": true,
        },
        //more settings
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a features class with each feature name and boolean setting created, I'm trying to do a

```
Features TenantFeatures = Configuration.GetSection("MultiTenant:Tenants:Features").GetChildren().Bind();
```

where `multiTenant.tenants.ID = 21341234-1234-2134-1234-123412342134`

I'm a bit stuck, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just bind against a configuration by using `IConfiguration.Bind<T>()`. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration)

### Model Classes

---

```cs
public class Tenant 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IDictionary<string, bool> Features {get;set;} = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
}

public class AppSettings {
    public Multitenancy Multitenancy { get;set;}
}

public class Multitenancy {
    public IEnumerable<Tenant> Tenants { get;set; } = Array.Empty<Tenant>();
}
```

### Binding `IConfiguration`

---

```cs
var options = config.Get<AppSettings>();
        foreach(var tenant in options.Multitenancy.Tenants)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tenant.Name);
            
            foreach(var feature in tenant.Features)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{feature.Key}: {feature.Value}");
            }
        }
```

Here you can find a [small working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7x0r6)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @martin, that's basically what i came up with,
i created a full DTO class for the Tenant and in three lines of code, have a really elegant solution

```
    public static Tenant GetFullTenantByTenantId(IConfiguration Configuration, Guid TenantId)
{
    MultiTenant allTenants = new();
    Configuration.Bind("Multitenancy", allTenants);
    return allTenants.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TenantId == TenantId);
}
```

i then access the tenant features with the following;

```
Tenant newTenant = GetFullTenantByTenantId(_config, TenantConfig.TenantId);

                //individual checks on the appsettings features
                if (newTenant.Features.FeatureName1)
                {
```